# Copy varying number of characters from a data frame column to a new column pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame defined as df. 
I'm trying to create a new column named, partialName by copying a column named, FullName, but only take a certain number of characters(including spaces) that is defined by a different column named, length.

```
*fullName*                                        
EPA Office 

Defense1 Info                                    

*length*

6

8
```

What I would like to get for the new column

```
*partialName*

EPA Of

Defense1
```

I tried using

```
x = df['length']
df['partialName'] = df['fullName'].str[:x]
```

but this is not working, if I replace X with a specific number then it does return that many characters but for me the numbers will vary. 
 What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can do `df['partialName']=df.apply(lambda row: row['fullName'][:row['length']], axis=1)`

Comment: I get the following: TypeError: ('slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: do you have missing values in length? my code works for me on your toy example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have missing values the following works for me:

```
In [21]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'fullName':['EPA Office','Defense1 Info','duff'] , 'length':[6,8,np.NaN]})
df

Out[21]:
        fullName  length
0     EPA Office       6
1  Defense1 Info       8
2           duff     NaN

In [24]:
df['partialName'] = df[df['length'].notnull()].apply(lambda row: row['fullName'][:int(row['length'])] , axis=1)
df

Out[24]:
        fullName  length partialName
0     EPA Office       6      EPA Of
1  Defense1 Info       8    Defense1
2           duff     NaN         NaN
```

So here we use `apply` and pass a lambda with param `axis=1` to operate row-wise to use the length value to slice the string, additionally as you have missing values the dtype is probably `float` so we need to mask the missing values out and cast the length value to int